# Laradock Nginx: This site can’t be reached

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, laradock

I'm stuck with `This site can’t be reached` error from my local docker container running Nginx from the latest [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/) installation.

I'm running Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6 on Windows 10 Enterprise (1709).

Everything worked fine a couple months before and today I wanted to run my sandbox project and faced this issue.

I've checked that `mysite.conf` is listed in "sites-available" directory of Nginx container.

Also I see that there are `mysite_access.log` and `mysite_error.log` in `/var/log` (both empty, because I tried to rename the site just to check if it helps).

Also, my test host is listed in `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.loc
```

The same server name is in `mysite.conf` file.

And still I have `This site can’t be reached` error when I try to open mysite.loc in the browser (Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Simple `localhost` is not accessible too.

Here's what `docker ps` gives me (ports are normally exposed):

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what else should I check or fix to get this running? Am I missing anything?

**UPD 1**:

I can `ping` my test host successfully, but still nothing in the browser:

```
> ping mysite.loc

Pinging mysite.loc [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

**UPD 2**:

But I cannot `telnet` to it:

```
> telnet mysite.loc
Connecting To mysite.loc...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

Comment: Because mysite.loc is mapped to 127.0.0.1, you'll be able to ping it no matter what. Also, you don't have port 23 mapped for the container, so you wouldn't be able to telnet on the default port even when everything is working. You can try telnetting to port 80 or 443 however.

Answer (score 1):

Today I've found out that there was a bug introduced by one of the previous updates when a new port forwarding for Windows was implemented: [docker/for-win#1506](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1506).

And it looks like that it was my issue. I've upgraded Docker to the latest version (Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6) and now my test host is reachable again (without any changes anywhere else).